# A function with zero gradient is locally constant

Tags: general-topology

A mapping $f:X\to Y$ is defined to be locally constant if $\forall x\in X$, there exists a neighbourhood $V(x)$ containing $x$ such that $a\in V(x)\implies f(a)=x_0$ for some constant $x_0$. In other words, **every point in that neighbourhood maps to the same image**.

My book says that if $\text{grad }f=0$ for all $x \in X$, then $f$ is locally constant.

Could someone give a proof of this fact? It has been confusing me for some time now!

Comment: They meant $grad f=0$ in a neighborhood of $x$ (or, maybe even everywhere in the domain).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut- Could you elaborate?

Comment: With the edit, your book is then true of course ;-) I remove my preceding comments.

Answer (score 7):

This is a special case of the mean value inequality for functions of several variables: if $|\nabla f|\le M$ on the line segment from $a$ to $b$, then 
$$
|f(a)-f(b)|\le M|a-b|
$$
The proof amounts to applying the usual mean value theorem to the one-variable function 
$$g(t)=\langle f(a+t(b-a)),b-a\rangle$$
which has $g(1)-g(0)=|f(b)-f(a)|^2$ and $|g'(t)| =| \langle f'(t), b-a\rangle|\le M|b-a|$.

In your case $M=0$.

Comment: Is $\langle x,y\rangle$ the inner product of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes, it must be.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Yes, it is.