# $\nabla U=0 \implies U=\mathrm{constant}$ with $A$ connected and $U$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, vector-analysis

I'm looking for suggestions on how to prove that

> Given a function $U: A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with $U \in C^1 $ (therefore continuous) and $A$ a
>   **connected set**, $$\nabla U=\bar{0} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall \bar{x} \in A\implies U=\mathrm{constant} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall \bar{x} \in
> A$$

In particular, how is the condition of $A$ as a **connected** necessary?

Comment: In fact, [you asked the same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045698/nabla-u-0-implies-u-mathrmconstant-only-if-u-is-defined-on-a-connected) recently